# How to use useMemo replacing useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I have options array for month and I am using it in `useEffect` but getting warning for deps.
Kindly guide how to use `useMemo`.
I am getting warning as given below:
The 'options' array makes the dependencies of `useEffect` Hook (at line 83) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'options' in its own `useMemo` Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```js
const options = [];

useEffect(() => {
  if (financialMonth) {
    options.forEach((item) => {
      if (Number(item.value) === Number(financialMonth)) {
        setMonthDefault(item.text);
      }
    });
    if (financialMonth.length === 0) setMonthDefault("April");
  }
}, [financialMonth, options]);
```

Comment: Actually, if options never changes at all, just don't set it as a dependency!

Comment: but i am getting warning to put options as deps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```js
const options = useMemo(() => [], [])
```

If you have a constant array of values (if it does not depend on state or props), then consider putting it outside of the component. That way you won't have to worry about `useMemo` or having it in the `useEffect` dependency array.

Comment: Extra points if you tell him to use useMemo instead of the useEffect here like `const defaultMonth = useMemo(...)`

Comment: I am learning from your input , let me try... thank you

Comment: Hi Andre, I have put options outside the component and it worked , thank you....